# How to make sure last AMQP message is published successfully before closing connection?

Tags: c++, rabbitmq, amqp

I have multiple processes working together as a system. One of the processes acts as main process. When the system is shutting down, every  process need to send a notification (via RabbitMQ) to the main process and then exit. The program is written in C++ and I am using [AMQPCPP library](https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP).

The problem is that sometimes the notification is not published successfully. I suspect exiting too soon is the cause of the problem as AMQPCPP library has no chance to send the message out before closing its connection.

The documentation of AMQPCPP says:

> Published messages are normally not confirmed by the server, and the RabbitMQ will not send a report back to inform you whether the message was succesfully published or not. Therefore the publish method does not return a Deferred object.
>
> As long as no error is reported via the Channel::onError() method, you can safely assume that your messages were delivered.
>
> This can of course be a problem when you are publishing many messages. If you get an error halfway through there is no way to know for sure how many messages made it to the broker and how many should be republished. If this is important, you can wrap the publish commands inside a transaction. In this case, if an error occurs, the transaction is automatically rolled back by RabbitMQ and none of the messages are actually published.

Without a confirmation from RabbitMQ server, it's hard to decide when it is safe to exit the process. Furthermore, using transaction sounds like overkill for a notification.

Could anyone suggest a simple solution for a graceful shutting down without losing the last notification?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I can setup a callback when closing the channel. So that I can safely close connection when all channels are closed successfully. I am not entirely sure if this process ensures all outgoing messages are really published. However from the test result, it seems that the problem is solved.

```
class MyClass
{
    ...
    AMQP::TcpConnection m_tcpConnection;
    AMQP::TcpChannel m_channelA;
    AMQP::TcpChannel m_channelB;
    ...
};

void MyClass::stop(void)
{
    sendTerminateNotification();

    int remainChannel = 2;
    auto closeConnection = [&]() {
        --remainChannel;
        if (remainChannel == 0) {
            // close connection when all channels are closed.
            m_tcpConnection.close();
            ev::get_default_loop().break_loop();
        }
    };

    auto closeChannel = [&](AMQP::TcpChannel & channel) {
        channel.close()
            .onSuccess([&](void) { closeConnection(); })
            .onError([&](const char * msg)
                {
                    std::cout << "cannot close channel: "
                            << msg << std::endl;
                    // close the connection anyway
                    closeConnection();
                }
            );

    closeChannel(m_channelA);
    closeChannel(m_channelB);
}
```